# PHP, Fire cookies on condition of pages

Tags: php, if-statement, cookies, conditional-statements

I'm having some trouble firing cookies on the condition of what page the user visits first.

Code below fires a cookie if on pages 2641, 2998, 2949 and no cookie exists. However, how do I do it to fire a different cookie if user is on any other page on the website if no cokkies exist?

Rule: Two cookies cannot exist. Just one or the other.

Any help much appreciated :)

```
if (is_page([2641,2998,2949]) && !isset($_COOKIE['ppc_campaign']) && !isset($_COOKIE['organic'])) {

    $ppc_cookie = "ppc_campaign";

    $ppc_value = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
    : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $path = "/";

    setcookie($ppc_cookie, strstr($ppc_value, '?'), time() + (86400 * 28), $path);

    $acf_applicationLink = $ppc_value;
    }   

else {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you want. Check for cookie existence. If neither exists, check the specific page, otherwise do something else.

```
if (!(isset($_COOKIE['ppc_campaign']) || isset($_COOKIE['organic']))) {
    if (is_page([2641,2998,2949])) {

        $ppc_cookie = "ppc_campaign";

        $ppc_value = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
        ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
        : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $path = "/";

        setcookie($ppc_cookie, strstr($ppc_value, '?'), time() + (86400 * 28), $path);

        $acf_applicationLink = $ppc_value;
    }   

    else {
        $organic_cookie = "organic";

        $organic_value = "?campaign=_ORGANIC_";

        $path = "/";

        setcookie($organic_cookie, $organic_value, time() + (86400 * 28), $path);

        $acf_applicationLink = $organic_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: So close! For some reason the values are not populating the links though.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the values of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']? Are they actually returning values? There are dozens of other threads on how to build up a URL/URI, many of the $_SERVER variables can be empty under different circumstances.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] instead?

Comment: So the $ppc_value works on the pages. When go onto the other pages the cookie holds which is good,  though the link on those pages doesn't hold the ppc_value for the url whis is what was hoping.

Same if it's the other way round. If any other page fires 'organic', should hold on those other pages.

Best way to explain is which ever pages are visits first creates whichever cookie and sets the url

Comment: Sounds like this might need a new question since it addresses a new issue. Sorry, it's hard to understand the relative questions without direct code references. What code did you put in the else?

Comment: I have added more code. It is close now. So if user is on PPC page, ppc cookie fires and captures the link. Good. However when go onto another page the cookie is still present which is good, except the link doesn't hold. ANy ideas?